# Run Thread with specific condition and time

Tags: java, multithreading, maven, mybatis

I want to create a condition where when the user places an order there is a thread that runs for 20 seconds to check the database whether the payment status is done or pending, if done then the thread will stop, if it is still pending then the thread will continue to run for 20 seconds and update the status in the database to be canceled,i'm using mybatis and XML mapper

> here is my code

```
public class PaymentCheck implements Runnable{
   private String username;
    public PaymentCheck(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        SqlSession session = MyBatisUtil.getSqlSessionFactory().openSession();
        Booking bookStatus =  session.selectOne("User.check",username);

        String status = bookStatus.getPayment_status();
        while (status.equalsIgnoreCase("pending")){
            final Timer timer = new Timer();
            timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
                int i = 6; // Time in seconds

                public void run() {
                    System.out.println(i--);
                    if (i < 0) {
                        timer.cancel();

                    }
                }
            }, 0, 1000);
        }
    }
}
```

> here is my code in controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/Booking", method = RequestMethod.POST,consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity<?> Booking(@RequestBody JSONObject jobj, @RequestHeader(HEADER)  String header) throws RestClientException, JsonProcessingException {

    String username = userRepo.claimToken(SECRET,PREFIX,header);
    jobj.put("username",username);
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    MediaType type = MediaType.parseMediaType("application/json; charset=UTF-8");
    headers.setContentType(type);
    System.out.println(jobj.toString());
    HttpEntity<JSONObject> formEntity = new HttpEntity<JSONObject>(jobj, headers);
    JSONObject json = restTemplate.postForEntity("http://localhost:8080/hotel/Booking", formEntity, JSONObject.class).getBody();
    String message = String.valueOf(json.get("Booking Status"));

    if (!message.equalsIgnoreCase("Failed")) {
        System.out.println("json:" + json.toString());
        System.out.println(username);
        PaymentCheck tq = new PaymentCheck(username);
        tq.run();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(json,HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }else{

        return new ResponseEntity<>(json,HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }


}
```

and here is the database

[image]

it don't show any error but also don't change anything...

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve.  Are you saying you want to wait for 20 seconds, check, and then decide whether to cancel or not?  Or are you saying you want to do this after 40 seconds, but have a check in the middle?  Why do you even need multi-threading for this?

Comment: I want if there is no payment during the 20 second time limit then the status in the database will be updated from pending to canceled

Comment: and if there is a payment and the status in the database is done then the thread will stop and do nothing

Comment: is there any simple ways?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be overcomplicating this.

**Problem 1**: your thread polls each second, but the controller response doesn't wait for the update to occur before responding to the customer.  So there's no point in polling.

**Problem 2**: your thread doesn't actually update the DB.

**Solutions**:

1. perform a check in the main thread, polling and then responding.
2. set a timer task for a single execution 20 seconds in the future to perform the update.

**Sample code for Solution 2 using generic JDBC**.

```
private Timer timer = new Timer();

@RequestMapping(value = "/Booking", method = RequestMethod.POST,consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity<?> Booking(@RequestBody JSONObject jobj, @RequestHeader(HEADER)  String header) throws RestClientException, JsonProcessingException {

    String username = userRepo.claimToken(SECRET,PREFIX,header);
    jobj.put("username",username);
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    MediaType type = MediaType.parseMediaType("application/json; charset=UTF-8");
    headers.setContentType(type);
    System.out.println(jobj.toString());
    HttpEntity<JSONObject> formEntity = new HttpEntity<JSONObject>(jobj, headers);
    JSONObject json = restTemplate.postForEntity("http://localhost:8080/hotel/Booking", formEntity, JSONObject.class).getBody();
    String message = String.valueOf(json.get("Booking Status"));

    if (!message.equalsIgnoreCase("Failed")) {
        System.out.println("json:" + json.toString());
        System.out.println(username);
        TimerTask tt = new PaymentCheck(username);
        timer.schedule(tt, 20000);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(json,HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }else{
        return new ResponseEntity<>(json,HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
}

public class PaymentCheck extends TimerTask {

   private static final MYQUERY = "update User.check set payment_status = 'cancelled' where payment_status = 'pending' and user = ?";

   private String username;

   public PaymentCheck(String username) {
       this.username = username;
   }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try (Connection cn = ...) {
            try (Statement stmt = new PreparedStatement(MYQUERY))
            {
                stmt.setString(1, username);
                stmt.execute();
                cn.commit();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm using my batis with XML mapper as my Database

Comment: okay i understand now, but it will error if after 20 s the status in database has been set to done right

Comment: nope.  Due to the conditional update where ```payment_status = 'pending'```, it will find no rows to update and be done with it.  I'm not familiar with my batis, so can't give you any tips there.